# Laravel Passport Password Grant Tokens: own mobile app

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

so my mobile app would be the client, i generated a client_id and a client_secret for it.

users who uses the mobile app have to login using their username/password.

Where should i store the client_id and client_secret? is it ok to expose them and simply place them hardcoded in the app?

Answer (score 8):

It is definitely not the secure way of hardcoding them and just placing them in an app.

Actually its not that straight forward. I assume you created the client from artisan or from the pre-built Vue components. In either case there is more that you have to do in order so safely consume the oauth2 api without exposing any potential security vulnerabilities in your app.

Assuming your mobile users would register from the mobile, you would need to create user and oAuth2 client from your mobile API that you will expose for your clients( mobile apps ) to consume. For this you have to do the following:

1. After installing laravel passport perform the following artisan command

   `php artisan migrate`

This will create the necessary tables to store oauth clients, their tokens and other related important information at db level. After this you would need to change client_id data type to VARCHAR(255) so as to store username as client_id instead of storing numeric client_ids.

2. Now go to your models and create a model for oauth_clients table so that you can create client pragmatically from the code while creating users.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App;


   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class oAuthClient extends Model
   {

   protected $table = 'oauth_clients';

   }
   ```

This will create a model class for you through which you can store oauth clients in the db while registering them in your app.

3. ```
   Route::post('/register-user', function () {

   $email= \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('email');
   $password=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('password');

   $user = new \App\User(array(
   'name' =>\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('name'),
   'email' => \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('email'),
   'password' => bcrypt(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::get('password')),
   ));
   $user->save();

   $oauth_client=new \App\oAuthClient();
   $oauth_client->user_id=$user->id;
   $oauth_client->id=$email;
   $oauth_client->name=$user->name;
   $oauth_client->secret=base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',$password, 'secret', true));
   $oauth_client->password_client=1;
   $oauth_client->personal_access_client=0;
   $oauth_client->redirect='';
   $oauth_client->revoked=0;
   $oauth_client->save();

   return [
   'message' => 'user successfully created.'
   ];
   });
   ```

This will generate an entry in user table and oauth_clients table which will be used by laravel passport to generate respective access_tokens for the user.In the above code snippet you have to note that to generate the oauth_client secret you have to use some strong formula of encryption that you feel comfortable using it with your application. Also use the same technique to generate the secret key on your mobile app for the respective client/user.

4. Now you can use the standard POST API offered by laravel passport to request access token through password grant using "oauth/token" using the following parameters:

   ```
   grant_type : 'password'
   client_id  : '<email with which the user is registered>'
   client_secret : '<generate the client secret from the mobile app>'
   username : '<email with which the user is registered>'
   password : '<password entered by the user>'
   scope : '<leave empty as default>'
   ```

5.The above will give you a response, if everything is correct, similar to :

```
    {
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 3155673600,
      "access_token":                 "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjMwZmM0MDk1NWY5YjUwNDViOTUzNDlmZjc2M2ExNDUxOTAxZjc5YTA5YjE4OWM1MjEzOTJlZmNiMDgwOWQzMzQwM2ExZWI4ZmMyODQ1MTE3In0.eyJhdWQiOiJzaHVqYWhtQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjMwZmM0MDk1NWY5YjUwNDViOTUzNDlmZjc2M2ExNDUxOTAxZjc5YTA5YjE4OWM1MjEzOTJlZmNiMDgwOWQzMzQwM2ExZWI4ZmMyODQ1MTE3IiwiaWF0IjoxNDc4MTQ1NjMyLCJuYmYiOjE0NzgxNDU2MzIsImV4cCI6NDYzMzgxOTIzMiwic3ViIjoiMSIsInNjb3BlcyI6W119.dj3g9b2AdPCK-im5uab-01SP71S7AR96R0FQTKKoaZV7M5ID1pSXDlmZw96o5Bd_Xsy0nUqFsPNRQsLvYaOuHZsP8v9mOVirBXLIBvPcBc6lDRdNXvRidNqeh4JHhJu9a5VzNlJPm3joBYSco4wYzNHs2BPSxXuuD3o63nKRHhuUHB-HwjVxj2GDwzEYXdZmf2ZXOGRJ99DlWGDvWx8xQgMQtd1E9Xk_Rs6Iu8tycjBpKBaC24AKxMI6T8DpelnFmUbMcz-pRsgCWCF_hxv6FpXav3jr1CLhhT58_udBvXjQAXEbtHeB7W_oaMcaqezHdAeOWDcnqREZHsnXHtKt0JpymcTWBkS2cg7sJzy6P9mOGgQ8B4gb8wt44_kHTeWnokk4yPFRZojkHLVZb8YL6hZxLlzgV1jCHUxXoHNe1VKlHArdlV8LAts9pqARZkyBRfwQ8oiTL-2m16FQ_qGg-9vI0Suv7d6_W126afI3LxqDBi8AyqpQzZX1FWmuJLV0QiNM0nzTyokzz7w1ilJP2PxIeUzMRlVaJyA395zq2HjbFEenCkd7bAmTGrgEkyWM6XEq1P7qIC_Ne_pLNAV6DLXUpg9bUWEHhHPXIDYKHS-c3N9fPDt8UVvGI8n0rPMieTN92NsYZ_6OqLNpcm6TrhMNZ9eg5EC0IPySrrv62jE",
      "refresh_token": "BbwRuDnVfm7tRQk7qSYByFbQKK+shYPDinYA9+q5c/ovIE1xETyWitvq6PU8AHnI5FWb06Nl2BVoBwCHCUmFaeRXQQgYY/i5vIDEQ/TJYFLVPRHDc7CKILF0kMakWKDk7wJdl5J6k5mN38th4pAAZOubiRoZ+2npLC7OSZd5Mq8LCBayzqtyy/QA5MY9ywCgb1PErzrGQhzB3mNhKj7U51ZnYT3nS5nCH7iJkCjaKvd/Hwsx2M6pXnpY45xlDVeTOjZxxaOF/e0+VT2FP2+TZMDRfrSMLBEkpbyX0M/VxunriRJPXTUvl3PW0sVOEa3J7+fbce0XWAKz7PNs3+hcdzD2Av2VHYF7/bJwcDCO77ky0G4JlHjqC0HnnGP2UWI5qR+tCSBga7+M1P3ESjcTCV6G6H+7f8SOSv9FECcJ8J5WUrU+EHrZ95bDtPc9scE4P3OEQaYchlC9GHk2ZoGo5oMJI6YACuRfbGQJNBjdjxvLIrAMrB6DNGDMbH6UZodkpZgQjGVuoCWgFEfLqegHbp34CjwL5ZFJGohV+E87KxedXE6aEseywyjmGLGZwAekjsjNwuxqD2QMb05sg9VkiUPMsvn45K9iCLS5clEKOTwkd+JuWw2IU80pA24aXN64RvOJX5VKMN6CPluJVLdjHeFL55SB7nlDjp15WhoMU1A="
    }
```

You can use these token safely from your client apps ( mobile apps ).
Hope it helps!.

Comment: So your take on this is that every user is a client. i am very new to oauth2 but it's not how i imagined it. i thought clients are not users, more like a service provider such as a mobile app, some server looking to integrate, etc ... 
so in my case my mobile app and web portal are clients. and my approach was to create a middleware that injects the  client_id and client_secret upon auth request.

Comment: Yes bro, if you want to provide access_token per individual using the mobile app you will need to provide each user with relevant access_tokens and thus deal them as a separate client so that their access_tokens through out the app could be manage separately. Secondly since each client from the mobile app will need to access the APIs with their own level of access you might need to have different scope levels for different users based on which only certain APIs access will be exposed to them. For these reasons each user is a client.

Comment: @ShujaAhmed Would you add anything to this after 2 years? I'm trying to implement exact same thing and can't decide whether to go with Passport or just take the easy way and use simple JWT.

Comment: I would suggest using JWT instead of passport because unfortunately not much work has been done on passport from the community mainly because JWT is emerging more as the common standard for authorization on server level. We have been using JWT for last 4 years now and have not even once faced any issues. With JWT encoding and decoding the payload, you get an extra option of security to apply where all the payload coming from your client is decoded while coming to and from the server and is decoded on the receiving end with respective signature. So JWT is what I will recommend

Comment: @ShujaAhmed Thank you for the reply. I am experimenting with the method you have posted above and I got it to work fine. One question that I have though, when I generate client_secret on server app and on mobile app, independently, how do I store it on my mobile app? On the server it's going to be in the oauth_clients table, but what about the mobile app?

Comment: On mobile it depends on the platform e.g. on iOS you can store it NsShRedUserDefaults, core data or local sqlite database.

Comment: @ShujaAhmed Could client_secret not be generated on mobile each time when user provides his password? Does it have to be stored on mobile from the moment user registers?

Comment: but that's not an ideal user flow, I mean you cant expect your user to provide username and password, or you cant store his username and password on the device to make the login request in the background queue on the app, because each oauth token has an expiry and they need to be regenerated and updated on the server. For security and safety purpose the generation of the oauth token should be managed by the server. Because you can control what happens on the server but you are limited as to what can be done on the device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167703/discussion-between-varin-and-shuja-ahmed).